# Ravel() 3D array in a peculiar order - Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, flatten

Let's say I have the following array:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

and I use the standard `ravel()` on it. That's what I get:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])
```

Instead, I need to ravel in a different order, which is:

```
0 9 18 1 10 19 2 11 20 3 12 21 4 13 22 5 14 23 6 15 24 7 16 25 8 17 26
```

unfortunately, even the `order` parameter in ravel, does not help, producing:

```
a.ravel(order='F')

array([ 0,  9, 18,  3, 12, 21,  6, 15, 24,  1, 10, 19,  4, 13, 22,  7, 16,
       25,  2, 11, 20,  5, 14, 23,  8, 17, 26])
```

This is the Fortran order, which is the closest thing that I have found to what I need, but still is not what I want.
Does someone know how to get the values in the order that I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a.transpose(1, 2, 0).ravel()
array([ 0,  9, 18,  1, 10, 19,  2, 11, 20,  3, 12, 21,  4, 13, 22,  5, 14,
       23,  6, 15, 24,  7, 16, 25,  8, 17, 26])
```